# FME - set symbology in TAB files in a directory

Tags: mapinfo, fme-form, tab

I want to set the symbology for all files in a directory. I found a way to do it with FME Workbench but it only works for one file. When I try to run it using batch deploy, it seems to be working for each file but I don't see any output.

I need to do this for about 600 files in 12 directories. It's fine if it just replaces the existing files with the new symbology.

The fmw is in https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BymNZZfQQ3a0VklIMnA3a215TG8/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
    Command-line to run this workspace:


    fme.exe tab_symbology_conversion.fmw
          --SourceDataset_MITAB P:\2013\567_Convert_XYZ_to_TAB\Working\Speewah\*.tab
          --DestDataset_MITAB P:\2013\567_Convert_XYZ_to_TAB\Working\symbolized\speewah
          --SourceDataset_MITAB_2 P:\2013\567_Convert_XYZ_to_TAB\Working\Speewah\345000_8131000_1k_1m_DEM_ESRI.tab


Starting translation...
FME 2013 SP1 (20130325 - Build 13450 - WIN64)
FME_HOME is 'C:\Program Files\FME\'
FME Professional Edition (node locked-crc)
Serial Number: 0
Temporary License: 13 days left.
Machine host name is: ATGIS25
START - ProcessID: 9120, peak process memory usage: 38420 kB, current process memory usage: 38420 kB
FME Configuration: Command line arguments are `C:\Program Files\FME\fme.exe' `P:/2013/567_Convert_XYZ_to_TAB/Working\wb-xlate-1386293055262_10812' `LOG_STANDARDOUT' `YES' `LogCount' `d:\Temp\wb-xlate-counts-1386293055440_10812'
Shared directories for formats are : C:\Users\georgec\Documents\FME\Formats;C:\Program Files\FME\datasources
Shared directories for transformers are : C:\Users\georgec\Documents\FME\Transformers;C:\Program Files\FME\transformers
Shared directories for coordinate systems are : C:\Users\georgec\Documents\FME\CoordinateSystems
Shared directories for coordinate system exceptions are : C:\Users\georgec\Documents\FME\CoordinateSystemExceptions
Shared directories for coordinate system grid overrides are : C:\Users\georgec\Documents\FME\CoordinateSystemGridOverrides
Shared directories for CS-MAP transformation exceptions are : C:\Users\georgec\Documents\FME\CsmapTransformationExceptions
Shared directories for transformer categories are : C:\Users\georgec\Documents\FME\TransformerCategories
FME Configuration: Reader Keyword is `MULTI_READER'
FME Configuration: Writer Keyword is `MULTI_WRITER'
FME Configuration: Writer Group Definition Keyword is `MULTI_WRITER_DEF'
FME Configuration: Reader type is `MULTI_READER'
FME Configuration: Writer type is `MULTI_WRITER'
FME Configuration: No destination coordinate system set
FME Configuration: Current working directory is `P:\2013\567_Convert_XYZ_to_TAB\Working'
FME Configuration: Temporary directory is `d:\Temp'
FME Configuration: FME_HOME is `C:\Program Files\FME\'
FME Configuration: FME_BASE is 'no'
FME Configuration: FME_MF_DIR is 'P:\2013\567_Convert_XYZ_to_TAB\Working/'
FME Configuration: FME_MF_NAME is 'tab_symbology_conversion.fmw'
FME Configuration: FME_PRODUCT_NAME is '2013 SP1'
System Status: 768766MB of disk space available in the FME temporary directory (d:\Temp\)
System Status: 8388419MB of virtual memory available
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 64-bit Service Pack 1 (Build 7601)
FME Platform: WIN64
Locale: en_US
Code Page: 1252  (ANSI - Latin I)
FME Configuration: Process limit is 16340 MB (out of 16340 MB physical memory and 8388607 MB address space)
FME Configuration: Start freeing memory when process usage exceeds 9804 MB of memory or 8388007 MB of address space
FME Configuration: Stop freeing memory when process usage is below 7353 MB of memory and 6291005 MB of address space
FME Configuration: Autodetermining optimal maximum number of objects in memory
MULTI_READER(MULTI_READER): Will fail with first member reader failure
MULTI_READER(MULTI_READER): Adding MITAB Reader with keyword MITAB_1
MULTI_READER(MULTI_READER): Adding MITAB Reader with keyword MITAB_2
Using Multi Reader $Revision: 93943 $ ( $Date: 2012-10-30 14:39:34 -0700 (Tue, 30 Oct 2012) $ ) with keyword `MULTI_READER' to read multiple datasets
FME Configuration: Reading 64 dataset(s) with MITAB reader identified by MITAB_1
MULTI_READER(MITAB_1): Will continue past member reader failures
MULTI_READER(MITAB_1): Adding MITAB Reader with keyword MITAB_1
Using Multi Reader $Revision: 93943 $ ( $Date: 2012-10-30 14:39:34 -0700 (Tue, 30 Oct 2012) $ ) with keyword `MITAB_1' to read multiple datasets
Trying to find a DYNAMIC plugin for reader named `MITAB'
Loaded module 'MITAB' from file 'C:\Program Files\FME\plugins/mitab_fme.dll'
FME API version of module 'MITAB' matches current internal version (3.7 20121025)
Using MapInfo (MITAB) Native Reader $Revision: 94856 $ ( $Date: 2012-11-14 11:13:57 -0800 (Wed, 14 Nov 2012) $ ) to open dataset `P:\2013\567_Convert_XYZ_to_TAB\Working\Speewah'
Using MultiWriter $Revision: 59162 $ ( $Date: 2009-04-07 10:04:59 -0700 (Tue, 07 Apr 2009) $ ) with keyword `MULTI_WRITER' to output data (ID_ATTRIBUTE is `multi_writer_id')
Writer output will be ordered by value of multi_writer_id
Loaded module 'LogCount_func' from file 'C:\Program Files\FME\plugins/LogCount_func.dll'
FME API version of module 'LogCount_func' matches current internal version (3.7 20121025)
Set encoding 'fme-system' from input feature
Opened native MapInfo file `P:\2013\567_Convert_XYZ_to_TAB\Working\Speewah\345000_8131000_1k_1m_DEM_ESRI.tab'
The OGC definition of the FME coordinate system 'MGA94-55' is 'Earth Projection 8, 116, "m", 147, 0, 0.9996, 500000, 10000000'
MITAB_1 Reader: Using Enhanced Geometry
FME Configuration: Source coordinate system for reader MITAB_1[MITAB] set to `MGA94-55' as read from input data
Coordinate System `MGA94-55' parameters: CS_NAME=`MGA94-55' DESC_NM=`Map Grid of Australia Zone 55 (GDA 94)' DT_NAME=`GDA94' GROUP=`AUSNZ' MAP_SCL=`1' MAX_LNG=`150.741246785833' MIN_LAT=`-90' MIN_LNG=`143.258753214167' PARM1=`147' PROJ=`TM' QUAD=`1' SCL_RED=`0.9996' SOURCE=`National Mapping COuncil of Australia, Special Publication 10' UNIT=`METER' X_OFF=`500000' Y_OFF=`10000000' ZERO_X=`0.001' ZERO_Y=`0.001' 
Reading source feature # 2500
Reading source feature # 5000
Reading source feature # 7500
<snip>
Reading source feature # 995000
Reading source feature # 997500
Reading source feature # 1000000
Closing native MapInfo reader
Trying to find a DYNAMIC plugin for reader named `MITAB'
FME API version of module 'MITAB' matches current internal version (3.7 20121025)
Using MapInfo (MITAB) Native Reader $Revision: 94856 $ ( $Date: 2012-11-14 11:13:57 -0800 (Wed, 14 Nov 2012) $ ) to open dataset `P:\2013\567_Convert_XYZ_to_TAB\Working\Speewah'
Set encoding 'fme-system' from input feature
Opened native MapInfo file `P:\2013\567_Convert_XYZ_to_TAB\Working\Speewah\345000_8132000_1k_1m_DEM_ESRI.tab'
MITAB_1 Reader: Using Enhanced Geometry
FME Configuration: Source coordinate system for reader MITAB_1[MITAB] set to `MGA94-55' as read from input data
Coordinate System `MGA94-55' parameters: CS_NAME=`MGA94-55' DESC_NM=`Map Grid of Australia Zone 55 (GDA 94)' DT_NAME=`GDA94' GROUP=`AUSNZ' MAP_SCL=`1' MAX_LNG=`150.741246785833' MIN_LAT=`-90' MIN_LNG=`143.258753214167' PARM1=`147' PROJ=`TM' QUAD=`1' SCL_RED=`0.9996' SOURCE=`National Mapping COuncil of Australia, Special Publication 10' UNIT=`METER' X_OFF=`500000' Y_OFF=`10000000' ZERO_X=`0.001' ZERO_Y=`0.001' 
Reading source feature # 1002500
Reading source feature # 1005000
Reading source feature # 1007500
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to set your input to all TAB files in a directory or multiple directories.

First, in the navigator pane, double click on the source of your input file:
[image]

Then, click on the little triangle on the right side of the dialog box:

[image]

Tick subdirectories if required.

[image]

You'll also want to expose the fme_dataset attribute:

[image]

Then, fanout on that fme_dataset attribute:
[image]

Note, I have not tested this but this is what I would do to get started.

Comment: Thanks, I don't see the 2nd graphic you show? how did you get this? is it possible for you to send me your fmw file?

Comment: @GeorgeC, I've edited my question to reflect this for you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but no luck. It just doesn't write or overwrites the same file. I would like to just overwrite each file or if necersary create a new file with same directory structure as the input. I have included the output from the system.

Comment: Ok, maybe you can't overwrite the same files.  Try looking into Parameters.  You can make the source directory the parameter, then use that same directory for your destination.  You can also use the source filename and add something like "_styled" at the end of the filename.  You might need the fme_basename attribute.  I also suggest when you create a new workspace, use "generate workspace" and select Dynamic Schema.